# Solve $x^2+x+7 \equiv 0\pmod{81}$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Solve $x^2+x+7\equiv 0 \pmod{81}$

---

My work:

Prime factorization $81 = 9^2 = 3^4$

Test the value $x\equiv0,1,2$ for $x^2+x+7\equiv0\mod{3}$

we have $x\equiv1\mod{3}$ works.

Now life this to $\mod{3^2} = \mod{9}$

Let $x=1+3k$ for some integer$k$

$(1+3k)^2 + (1+3k) +7 \equiv0\mod{9}$

$1+6k+0+1+3k+7\equiv0\mod{9}$

$9+9k\equiv0\mod9$

$1+k\equiv0\mod9$

$k\equiv-1\mod9$

$k=-1+9m$ for some integer m

Lift again to $\mod81$

$(-1+9m)^2 + (-1+9m)+7\equiv0\mod81$

$-9m+7\equiv0\mod81$

I cant continue... how can I make it work???

thanks!!

Comment: $9+9k\equiv0\mod9$ would imply any value of k works for the mod 9 case, no?

Comment: All natural number $\mathbb{N}$ and integers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can write the equation as $(x +41)^{2} \equiv -27$ (mod 81). But this means there is no solution, as $x+41$ would need to be divisible by $9.$ I'll put in more explanation, in view of comments and questions, including correcting a sign error pointed out in the comments.
We have $x^{2} + x + 7 \equiv x^{2}+ 82x + 7 $ (mod 81). This is (mod 81), equal to $(x+41)^{2}+ 7 -1600,$ and also $1600 \equiv -20$ (mod 81). Hence we need 
$(x+41)^{2} \equiv -27$ (mod 81), which is impossible in integers.

Comment: How did you come up with the 41 and 27??

Comment: If you write $x=82x$ then the $41$ comes from completing the square. Unless I'm making a mistake, the $27$ should actually be $54$.

Comment: but why $x=82x$...?

Comment: Because $1\equiv 82  (mod 81)$ I'm thinking.

Comment: Yes, the idea is to rewrite $x^2+x+7$ as $(x+a)^2+b$. The right hand side is $x^2+2xa+(a^2+b)$, so $2a\equiv 1\pmod{81}$, so $a\equiv41\pmod{81}$. We then have $a^2+b\equiv61+b\equiv7\pmod{81}$, or $b\equiv 27\pmod{81}$. That, is the equation can be rewritten as $(x+41)^2+27\equiv0\pmod{81}$. (Note the typo in the sign in the stated solution.)

Answer (score 3):

Let's argue following your approach: As you say, $x$ must be of the form $3k+1$. We then have that $$x^2+x+7=9k^2+9k+9=9(k^2+k+1).$$ This is a multiple of $81=9\times 9$ iff $9$ divides $k^2+k+1$. Again, arguing as you did, we see that $k$ must have the form $3t+1$ for some integer $t$, and then $$k^2+k+1=9t^2+9t+3=9(t^2+t)+3,$$ which *never* is a multiple of $9$, so there are no solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Let us do the lifting, patiently. As was pointed out, the solution $x\equiv 1\pmod{3}$ lifts to **three** solutions modulo $3^2$, namely $1$, $4$, and $7$.

Let us try to now lift to $3^3$. We do only the case $x\equiv 1\pmod 3^2$. Let $x=1+9k$ for some $k$. Then $x^2+x+7\equiv 1+18k+1+9k+7\equiv 27k+9\pmod{3^3}$. It is clear that there is no $k$ that works. A similar calculation shows that the solutions $x\equiv 4\pmod{3^2}$ and $x\equiv 7\pmod{3^2}$ do not lift to $3^3$.

Comment: Thats the thing i dont understand. How do you know 1,4,6 works for modulo 9?
and how did you come up with the number 27?

Comment: From *your* lifting to $9$ calculation, you were looking for solutions mod $9$ of the shape $1+3k$, where $k=0$, $1$, or $2$. Then you calculated correctly and got $9(1+k)\equiv 0\pmod{9}$. You concluded incorrectly that $k+1\equiv 0\pmod{9}$. In fact, $9(1+k)$ is **always** congruent to $0$ mod $9$. So any $k$ works. The only candidates are $k=0$, $1$, $2$, giving the solutions $1$, $4$, and $7$ for $x^2+x+7\equiv 0\pmod{9}$. It is at the *nest* stage, from $9=3^2$ to $27=3^3$, that lifting fails.

Comment: so.....the end is "no solution"?

Comment: Yes, all this work for nothing.